# WPF DataGrid, handle keys and no data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have some DataGrid, data is bind to my collection (`INotifyCollectionChanged`).

Records has to be prefilled when you create new one. So I disabled adding in dataGrid (`CanUserAddRows="False"`) and handle “PreviewKeyUp” event (when user press ctrl+N, execute method “CreateRecord” – notify of added new record).

This scenario work perfectly… almost.

`PreviewKeyUp` was fired only if some element in grid is focused (e.g. DataGridRow). But if I don’t have any record, there is no focus and event was never fired.

So my question is: If is it possible to somehow handle keys ctrl+N when DataGrid is empty? E.g. trigging Focusable or something like this.

Another workaround would be to “catch” somehow adding row and fill required fields, but...
Standard NewItemPlaceholder will be fine, but EditableItems use item constructor with no parameters.
And this is another think I couldn't use (or I just don't known how :D)

My Data has to be created with predefined values (like createdUserId).

Some code to clarify:

```cs
public MyItemsCollection Items { get; set; }

public MyItemType CreateRecord()
{
    MyItemType item = new MyItemType(userId);
    item.InitValues();
    Items.Add(item);
    return item;
}

/********/

public void dataGrid_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.N && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        CreateRecord();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" PreviewKeyUp="dataGrid_PreviewKeyUp">
```

Any one has some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to attach to the Window's PreviewKeyUp... and if no record in the data grid, force it... or just force it regardless.  As long as the person is in that form, it could be implied to do it if the form OR the grid has the focus for such key press.

Comment: But what if I have 2 DataGrid on the form... how I recognize in which grid user attempt to add new row?

Comment: @Carnifex, then you could optionally "ask" the user... Add new record to "grid A" or "grid B" and work from that... OR, just imply one of the grids is the "default" grid that records will be added to.

Comment: "default" grid is not a option: two grids - headers, lines. User could (or must) add header information and then details-lines

Comment: ask user with grid... also not posible - I imagine client reaction when I told him "you always be asked with grid you want add record" :D  option I impemented for now is button "add" near each grid - but this mess up the design. So I want some normal solution instead of workarounds

Comment: @Carnifex, i was just replying on your original intent to capture keypress at form level.  With a dual grid, that would definitely be button controls, but so many people have different UI visions, no ONE solution is definitely the best